# Неправильное отображение multirow

Tags: вёрстка, latex

В таблице понадобилась ячейка, которая объединяет несколько строк в одном столбце, за это отвечает пакет `multirow`, и вроде синтаксис простой, но я не могу добиться нормального отображения текста. Текст выезжает за ячейку - либо по вертикали, либо по горизонтали.

Сначала я думал, что у пакета несовместимость с `xltabular`, но похожее поведение наблюдается и в `longtable` и в обычном `tabular` (у которых в документации `multirow`, вроде как заявлена совместимость).

Минимальный код:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14bp,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

% Подключение пакетов
\usepackage{polyglossia}    %для русского языка
\usepackage{cmap} % поиск в PDF
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, footskip=10mm]{geometry} %задаёт поля документа
\usepackage{amsmath} %пакет мат. формул
\usepackage{ulem}   %пакет для подчёркиваний
\usepackage{graphicx} %пакет для вставки рисунков
\usepackage{float} %плавающие объекты
\usepackage{caption} %заголовки плавающих объектов
\usepackage{longtable} %таблицы на несколько листов
\usepackage{xltabular} 
\usepackage{array} %для таблиц
\usepackage{multirow} %объединение строк

% Установка параметров для документа
\setdefaultlanguage[forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}  % устанавливает главный язык документа, опция - убирает последнюю точку в нумерации заголовков
\setotherlanguage{english} %% объявляет второй язык документа
\pagestyle{plain} %номера страниц будут печататься снизу и при этом колонтитулов не будет

\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont{Liberation Sans}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
\frenchspacing  %после знаков препинания пробелы не увеличиваются (по умолчанию эти пробелы увеличиваются в соответствии с англо-саксонской традицией)

% Команды для документа
%===================================================
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\textlang{english}{\textit{#1}}} %весь английский язык - курсивом
%нумерация вложенных списков
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii})}
%переопределение символа списков
\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}

\begin{document}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{0.15\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.07\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
        \caption{Размещение объектов    \label{Object-location-rules}} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Объект} & \textbf{Поле} & \textbf{Допустимое кол-во объектов в одной клетке} & \textbf{Минимальное расстояние между клетками с объектом (кол-во клеток)} & \textbf{Максимальное кол-во объектов на поле} \\ \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{5}{r}{Продолжение таблицы \thetable} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Объект} & \textbf{Поле} & \textbf{Допустимое кол-во объектов в одной клетке} & \textbf{Минимальное расстояние между клетками с объектом (кол-во клеток)} & \textbf{Максимальное кол-во объектов на поле} \\ \hline
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{5}{r}{Продолжение таблицы на следующей странице}
        \endfoot
        \hline
        \endlastfoot
        
        \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{Банановая пальма, кокосовая пальма, финиковая пальма}
        & \eng{D} & 1 & 0 & 96 \\
        \cline{2-5}
        & \eng{O} & 3 & 0 & 48 \\
        \hline
        Нефть & \eng{D} ИЛИ \eng{O} & 1 & - & 1 \\
    \end{xltabular}
    
    \begin{longtable}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{0.15\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.07\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.26\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.26\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.26\linewidth}|}
        \caption{Размещение объектов    \label{Object-location-rules2}} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Объект} & \textbf{Поле} & \textbf{Допустимое кол-во объектов в одной клетке} & \textbf{Минимальное расстояние между клетками с объектом (кол-во клеток)} & \textbf{Максимальное кол-во объектов на поле} \\ \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{5}{r}{Продолжение таблицы \thetable} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{Объект} & \textbf{Поле} & \textbf{Допустимое кол-во объектов в одной клетке} & \textbf{Минимальное расстояние между клетками с объектом (кол-во клеток)} & \textbf{Максимальное кол-во объектов на поле} \\ \hline
        \endhead
        \multicolumn{5}{r}{Продолжение таблицы на следующей странице}
        \endfoot
        \hline
        \endlastfoot
        
        \multirow{2}{*}{Банановая пальма, кокосовая пальма, финиковая пальма}
        & \eng{D} & 1 & 0 & 96 \\
        \cline{2-5}
        & \eng{O} & 3 & 0 & 48 \\
        \hline
        Нефть & \eng{D} ИЛИ \eng{O} & 1 & - & 1 \\
    \end{longtable}
    
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{0.15\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.07\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.26\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.26\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.26\linewidth}|}
        
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{\textwidth}{Банановая пальма, кокосовая пальма, финиковая пальма}
        & \eng{D} & 1 & 0 & 96 \\
        \cline{2-5}
        & \eng{O} & 3 & 0 & 48 \\
        \hline
        Нефть & \eng{D} ИЛИ \eng{O} & 1 & - & 1 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Результат отображения следующий:
[image: результат отображения]

Не могу понять, в чём проблема. То ли пакет с чем-то не совместим, то ли я где-то невнимательно ознакомился с документацией...

Дистрибутив: TeXLive

Компилятор: XeLaTeX

P.S. Знаю, что можно отказаться от `multirow` в пользу команды `cline`, но страдает равномерное распределение текста по ячейке. Да и просто хочется сделать красиво =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я на всякий случай напишу, что я тоже могу поведение команды `\multirow` понимать не совсем верно :-), но...  Скорее всего, Вы невнимательно ознакомились с документацией. Вы хотите от команды `\multirow` чего-то, что ей не свойственно - если я правильно понимаю, Вы хотите, чтобы она Вам автоматически увеличивала высоту строк. А она занимается тем, что просто накладывается на нижние или верхние строки, она их не заменяет и не раздвигает. Если в этих ячейках окажется текст, то она просто нарисует свой текст поверху. Заботиться о том, чтобы "захваченных" строк хватало должны Вы сами. (*В пользу этого объяснения могу еще сказать, что latex не может знать, высоту какой из строк он должен для Вас увеличить.*)
Правда, пакет multirow даёт в помощь кое-какие средства, чтобы Вам было удобнее бороться с высотой строк. Но об этом чуть ниже.

Теперь немного про ошибки. (*Кстати, у меня почему-то Ваш пример отказался добровольно компилироваться (TeXLive 2021, MS Win10), поэтому я повыбрасывал кучу лишнего, чтобы получить работающий пример.*) По горизонтали текст вылезает за границы именно потому, что Вы его сами попросили так делать: в двух случаях задали размер ширины ячейки на длину строки (`\multirow{2}{\linewidth}{...}` и `\multirow{2}{\textwidth}{...}`), а в одном случае перевели ячейку из типа парбокса (p{}) в однострочный вариант (с типом столбцов l,c или r): `\multirow{2}{*}{...}` - об этом поведении спецификатора `*` сказано в документации. Ну а в оставшемся варианте, как я уже писал, latex все сделал правильно, это просто Вы его не поняли.

Таким образом, Вам осталось только вручную увеличить высоту тех двух строк, на которые наезжает `\multirow`. Если делать это через команду `\\[30pt]`,то получится вариант, когда содержимое строк будет по вертикали располагаться ближе к верху ячеек и смотрится это не очень хорошо. И чтобы хоть как-то сохранить презентабельность таких строк (которым приходится соседствовать с многострочными ячейками) автор пакета multirow сделал еще один пакет: **bigstrut**. Он позволяет увеличивать высоты таких строк на заданную величину (задается командой типа: `\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{20pt}`). Но это как бы решает проблему внешнего вида только для тех строк, которые перекрываются ячейками с `\multirow`. Но у Вас еще есть строки (там где про нефть) - там выравнивание будет по верху ячеек.. и как правильнее оформить такой вариант я не могу сказать. Возможно, для такой строки тоже нужно использовать `\multirow` и добавить строк.

В общем, я немного порезал исходный пример, оставил только longtable (просто так получилось :-) ), изменил размеры таблицы и получилось примерно так:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14bp,a4paper]{scrreprt}

% Подключение пакетов
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage{polyglossia}    %для русского языка
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}   %внутренняя кодировка
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, footskip=10mm]{geometry} %задаёт поля документа

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}  
\setotherlanguage{english} %% объявляет второй язык документа
\setmainfont{Arial}


% Команды для документа
%===================================================
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\textlang{english}{\textit{#1}}} %весь английский язык - курсивом

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
    
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt} % это чтобы верхняя часть строки не "прилипала" к горизонтальным линиям
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{20pt} 

\begin{longtable}{|P{0.15\textwidth}|P{0.07\textwidth}|P{0.24\textwidth}|P{0.24\textwidth}|P{0.24\textwidth}|}
    \caption{Размещение объектов    \label{Object-location-rules2}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Объект} & \textbf{Поле} & \textbf{Допустимое кол-во объектов в одной клетке} & \textbf{Минимальное расстояние между клетками с объектом (кол-во клеток)} & \textbf{Максимальное кол-во объектов на поле} \\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{Продолжение таблицы \thetable} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Объект} & \textbf{Поле} & \textbf{Допустимое кол-во объектов в одной клетке} & \textbf{Минимальное расстояние между клетками с объектом (кол-во клеток)} & \textbf{Максимальное кол-во объектов на поле} \\ \hline
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{Продолжение таблицы на следующей странице}
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    
    \multirow{2}[t2]{0.15\textwidth}[-7pt]{Банановая пальма, кокосовая пальма, финиковая пальма}
    & \eng{D} \bigstrut & 1 & 0 & 96 \\
    \cline{2-5}
    & \eng{O} \bigstrut & 3 & 0 & 48 \\
    \hline
     & \multirow{3}{0.07\textwidth}{\centering \eng{D} ИЛИ   \eng{O}} & & & \\
    Нефть &                     & 1 & - & 1 \\ 
    & & & &
\end{longtable}
    
\end{document}
```

Из мелочей, еще я объявил новый тип столбцов `P`, чтобы не загромождать и без того сложный заголовок таблицы.

[image: Пример таблицы]

Вообще, оформление таблиц в техе (и всех его наследниках), особенно с такими командами как `multirow` очень сложная тема, которая требует много ручной подгонки.

Ну и на всякий случай оставлю источники:

1. [Официальный мануал по Multirow](https://mirror.truenetwork.ru/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/multirow.pdf) - здесь стоит обратить внимание на страницы: 6-8,10,11-17. На стр. 15 прямо Ваш случай.
2. [LaTeX Table Hints and Tips](https://statatexblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/tabletricks_latex.pdf) - здесь интересны по теме страницы 10, 11. Хотя можно и всю статью прочитать, она весьма интересная.

Comment: Благодарю! Насчёт преамбулы - она у меня всегда очень большая, вынесена в отдельный файл. Поэтому, когда её сокращаю - это ещё тот квест, и бывает, что остаётся лишнее. Ваш пример работает, только пришлось сменить шрифт. В целом, таблицы в Латех - пока что моя головная боль, ещё осваиваю их.